# logrotate deleted the file instead of rotating

Tags: apache, logrotate

Why would logrotate delete the file instead of rotating it?

Here's the config:

```
/var/log/httpd/*log {
    size 1G
    missingok
    notifempty
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
    /bin/kill -HUP `cat /var/run/httpd.pid 2>/dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
    endscript
}
```

Comment: What did the solution end up being? The accepted answer suggests a few things so some further insight would be helpful!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your config looks ok, there is likely some default in your /etc/logrotate.conf that is deleting files.

If you have `rotate 0` in your config file, old files will be deleted rather than rotated.

It may be that the files are being rotated but you are looking in the wrong place. 
Check the logrotate logs with `cat /var/lib/logrotate/status` to verify that logrotate is running as expected. 
And of course, familiarize yourself with logrotate by reading the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate)

Comment: `logrotate -d` should have shown the effective config. Thanks to this post, I know `rotate 0` in the /etc/logrotate.conf is the culprit troubling me for long!